# Convert PDF to 300 pixels per inch TIFF

Tags: applescript, pdf

I need to convert an existing PDF document into TIFF.

The following code works, -

```
tell application "Preview"
    activate
    open POSIX file "/Users/john/Desktop/12.pdf"
    save front document in file "Macintosh HD:Users:john:Desktop:12.tiff"
end tell
```

but the resulting TIFF is 72 pixels per inch, whereas I want it to be 300.

I have tried to change the last line to

```
save front document in file "Macintosh HD:Users:john:Desktop:12.tiff {with options: ...}"
save front document in file "Macintosh HD:Users:john:Desktop:12.tiff {with properties: ...}"
```

but this doesn't seem to work. How it can be achieved?

Comment: What did you actually write instead of ... for the options/properties? I have a python script that does this very well, which works in Automator or Shortcuts, but you'll need to install python3 and pyobjc.

Comment: 72 dpi is the standard pixel density for printed documents.  I like to use GraphicsMagic for this type of work, but there’s a utility you can try that might solve your needs.  Issue the command `sips —setProperty dpiWidth 300 —setProperty dpiHeight 300 foobar.tif`. Let me know if that works.  If not, I have a GM command that definately will.  (There are two dashes before each flag - it looks like just one dash on a browser).

Comment: @Allan Point of order. 72dpi is the default pixel density for images on MacOS. It's not any kind of 'standard' for printed documents.

Comment: @benwiggy 72dpi was/is the default because it was the resolution that printers and monitors could produce back in the day.  A PDF document to this day defaults at 72dpi.  https://www.pixelperfectcreative.com/blog/72-dpi-why

Comment: @Alan Yes, I know a bit about the history... My issue is with the word "standard", in place of "default", which could have unfortunate and unforeseen connotations.

Comment: @Allan It seems `sips` doesn't allow to convert multipage PDFs to multipage TIFFs, which is my case.

Comment: Apply `sips` to the tiff only.  See if that works

Comment: @wch1zpink It is possible to save multipage PDF as multipage TIFF by opening PDF using Preview and then to click File > Export > ...

Comment: I'm still puzzling why you'd want to rasterise something which is infinitely scalable as vector...

Answer (score 1):

The Shortcuts.app has an action to "Make a TIFF image from PDF".

You can create a workflow with this action, and use it as a Quick Action in the Finder.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, sound interesting. How can I open this window? Where to find it?

Comment: @jsx97 It's in the Shortcuts app, which is the 'successor' to Automator.

Comment: Aha, I see, thanks. I didn't know about Shortcuts before. The only problem with this solution is that a target PDF file contains multiple pages, and I don't understand how to tell Shortcuts to export multipage PDF as multipage TIFF instead of multiple TIFF files.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's definitely not pretty but, assuming that Preview.app is already running, this following **AppleScript** code should work on the currently visible doc in Preview.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Preview"
        set frontmost to true
        repeat until frontmost
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
        delay 0.1
        click menu item "Export…" of menu "File" of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
        delay 0.1
        repeat until pop up button 2 of sheet 1 of window 1 exists
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
        click pop up button 2 of sheet 1 of window 1
        delay 0.1
        click menu item "TIFF" of menu 1 of pop up button 2 of sheet 1 of window 1
        delay 0.1
        repeat until sheet 1 of window 1 exists
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
        delay 0.1
        try
            set focused of sheet 1 of window 1 to true
        end try
        delay 0.1
        keystroke tab
        repeat until text field 4 of sheet 1 of window 1 exists
            try
                set focused of text field 4 of sheet 1 of window 1 to true
            end try
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
        delay 0.1
        set value of text field 4 of sheet 1 of window 1 to "300"
        -- delay 0.1
        -- click button "Save" of sheet 1 of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```